# How to create a fix height and width of button in android at any position

Tags: android, button

> Hello guys just wanna ask about creating like the image below ..  i
>   search all about it here but fail to see similar on my question .i
>   know i would use layout_weight but cant do what i want it to be
>   like.see attachment below .. i wanted to do atleast 3 buttons .any
>   help please ?

**https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/149364_1489250518001074_8490520321510060718_n.jpg?oh=647bbe485caabf52ad8de32e5e7412ac&oe=54B27214&__gda__=1424652329_8648e09f0cbd8b85c95ec64ebf14d1b9**

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you show some code?

Comment: i tried only editing at xml layout .putting 3 buttons and add layout_width with 1 on each .it was perfect but what i want is like the picture it is side by side by the each other and seeing those borders

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this pretty easily using a Gridview layout. You would create a gridview with a column number of 3 and just add 6 items to the gridview. You will also have to override the getView method of the adapter for the Gridview and return a imageview that contains the image you want to display.

Follow this guide for more instruction about using layouts, then try and follow the instructions I laid out above.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/